# Python export some list and put all in for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I am writing a program that exports monitoring data.

I have python code which sends API requests and gets a response as json in form of a dictionary.

Responses look like this:

```
[
  {
    "diskwrite": 667719532544,
    "name": "test-hostname",
    "maxmem": 536870912,
    "diskread": 876677015576,
    "mem": 496111616,
    "id": "qemu/102",
    "node": "node1",
    "template": 0,
    "cpu": 0.00947819269772254,
    "vmid": 102,
    "type": "qemu",
    "maxcpu": 2,
    "netout": 15081562546,
    "maxdisk": 10737418240,
    **"status": "running",**
    "netin": 15852619497,
    "disk": 0,
    "uptime": 3273086
  },
  {
    "maxcpu": 8,
    "type": "qemu",
    "vmid": 106,
    "cpu": 0.500598230113925,
    "template": 0,
    "node": "node1",
    "id": "qemu/106",
    "mem": 10341007360,
    "maxmem": 10737418240,
    "diskread": 8586078094720,
    "name": "some.other-hostname",
    "diskwrite": 6052378838016,
    "uptime": 1900411,
    "disk": 0,
    "netin": 4899018841106,
    **"status": "stopping",**
    "maxdisk": 107374182400,
    "netout": 4788420573355
  },
  ...
```

I'd like to loop through all the hostnames and their items as is ("diskwrite", "mem", "cpu", etc) but I'd like to add these items to a dictionary only if they have a status of running ("status":"running").

```
ram_metric.set({'type': "total"}, ram[0])
cpu_metric.set({'type': 'average', 'interval': '5 minutes'}, cpu[0])
```

I also need a loop that will make this line of code and for every "name" item creating this row with host=name:

```
ram_metric = Gauge("memory_usage_bytes", "Memory usage in bytes.",
                       {'host': host})
cpu_metric = Gauge("cpu_usage_percent", "CPU usage percent.",
                       {'host': host})
```

Please, I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Your file is in JSON format?

Comment: am i the only one that didn't understand a thing ? i'm sorry i find your question asked in a very bad way..

Comment: I reformulated question, sorry !

Comment: Resolved ! `metric = get_all_vm()
        
        for item in metric:

            for key,value in item.items():
                if key == "mem":
                    ram_metric.set({'name': item['name'], 'type': 'usage'}, item['mem'])
                elif key == "cpu":
                    cpu_metric.set({'name': item['name'], 'type': 'load'}, item['cpu'])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can try to help.

The response you are getting is a list with dictionaries and you are only interested if the status is running so first:

```
def get_all_vm():
    all_vm = get_request("/api2/json/cluster/resources?type=vm")
    vm = all_vm['data']
    list = [item for item in vm if item['status'] == "running"]
    return list
metric = get_all_vm()
```

Now you can loop through all the items and (1) add new values by item["newkey"] = newvalue or (2) loop through existing keys with dict iteration

```
for item in metric:
   item["justanexample"] = "test"
   for key,value in item.items():
       if key == "mem":
           ram_metric.set({'name': metric['data']['name'], 'type': 'usage'}, metric['data']['mem'])
       elif key == "cpu":
           cpu_metric.set({'name': metric['data']['name'], 'type': 'load'}, metric['data']['cpu'])
...
```

Comment: How to add loop for this line of code, for host I must to add "name" item `ram_metric = Gauge("memory_usage_bytes", "Memory usage in bytes.",
                       {'host': host})`

Comment: I added this to my code. But I got error too many values to unpack (expected 2) ```metric = get_all_vm()
        

        for key,value in metric:
            if key == "mem":
                ram_metric.set({'name': metric['data']['name'], 'type': 'usage'}, metric['data']['mem'])
            elif key == "cpu":
                cpu_metric.set({'name': metric['data']['name'], 'type': 'load'}, metric['data']['cpu'])```

Comment: @Petar Check my updated code again:
If you have Python 2.7 use .iteritems()
If you have Python 3 use .items()

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am not understanding your question correctly, since I am having a little trouble understanding exactly what you want.

If you want to get a list of all host-names you can do the following.
You can use a list comprehension for this.  Something like:

```
running_hosts =  [running_host['name'] for running_host in my_list_of_dicts if running_host['status'] == "running"]
```